# ASP.Net MVC Razor - Display Countries Gives Error in View

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to list the contries in view. I have created a model called tbl_Countries and the code is below

```
public class tbl_Countries
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Country_Name { get; set; }
}
```

I have a Controller called Home with the following code. I have created an edmx file for TestDB database

```
public ActionResult Index()
{            
    TestDBEntities TestdbContext = new TestDBEntities();
    var countries = TestdbContext.tbl_Countries.ToList();
    return View(countries);
}
```

Below is my View code
    @model IList 
displaying the countries using ul li with foreach

If i run the application am getting this error:

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List1[TestMVC.tbl_Countries]', 
but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList1[TestMVC.Models.tbl_Countries]
```

I just want to show the list of countries in view and I would like to know 
    Without creating a model class is it possible to bind grid?
    Is it mandatory to specify the model name using `@model` directive in view?

Comment: Show your view, please

Answer (score 0):

You got this error 'cause you specified in your view @model List, but pass to it List, try to change it in your view to List

Yes, you can delete @model at all, but in this case your view won't be strongly typed, so you won't be able to use intelli sense

Answer (score 0):

create a list of country type in model

```
    public List< tbl_Countries> country{get;set;}
```

In index page set the value of this List

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {            
     TestDBEntities TestdbContext = new TestDBEntities();
     tbl_Countries objModel=new tbl_Countries(); 
     objModel.country = TestdbContext.tbl_Countries.ToList();
     return View(objModel);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message you are expecting a model of the type `List<TestMVC.Models.tbl_Countries>` in the view which is different from the `List<TestMVC.tbl_Countries>` type your action method returns.

To resolve this issue, you could create a list your view expects and map the data you got from Entity Framework to it.

For example:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{            
 TestDBEntities TestdbContext = new TestDBEntities();
 var countries = new List<TestMVC.Models.tbl_Countries>();
 countries = (from country in TestdbContext.tbl_Countries
              select new TestMVC.Models.tbl_Countries
              { 
                  Country_Name = country.Country_Name
              }).toList();

 return View(countries);
}
```

To seperate the logic of the view and data access it is a good practice to have models which are independent from your data models, from the EF models in your example.